# Problema com input e tupla em Python

Tags: python, input, tupla

Estou tendo problemas em fazer com que o programa interprete o meu dado de entrada e relacione com as informações contidas na tupla.

**Enunciado:**

> Dada a tupla abaixo:
>
> t1 = ('Doce', 'Churrasco', 'Bala ', 'Tapioca', 'Pizza ', 'Feijão ',
> 'Arroz ', 'Açaí ', 'Paçoca ', 'Acarajé', 'Pamonha', 'Dobradinha', 'Rapadura')
>
> Faça um programa que:
>
> O usuário digita uma comida e seu programa diz em qual posição do
> cardápio esse item está e printe os itens em ordem alfabética para o
> usuário

**Minha tentativa de solução**

```
t7 = ('Doce', 'Churrasco', 'Bala ', 'Tapioca', 'Pizza ', 'Feijão ', 
      'Arroz ', 'Açaí ', 'Paçoca ', 'Acarajé', 'Pamonha', 'Dobradinha', 'Rapadura')

x = input('Digite a comida preterida: ')

print(t7.index(x))
print(sorted(t7))
```

Esse foi o jeito que pensei para solução do problema, porém ao informar o valor da string "x" o programa dá esse erro como resposta: **ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple**.
Já tentei trocar a variável de "x" para tupla, porém o erro persistiu.

Gostaria de saber o porquê disso acontecer.
Agradeço desde já.

Comment: O erro acontece porque o valor que você fornece para a variável `x` através da digitação no seu teclado (via função `input`) não está batendo com nenhum valor dentro da tupla `t7`. Confira se você está digitando algo que existe de fato em `t7`. Note que Python considera strings com/sem acentos, com letras maiúsculas/minúsculas, e com/sem espaço em branco como coisas diferentes, isto é, `"Feijao"` não é o mesmo que `"  feijão  "`.

Answer (score 0):

você colocou no índice 3 'Bala ' , um espaço entre bala e aspas , então teria que digitar Bala + espaço , tira o espaço de todos os índices e aconselho no final da variável x por um .capitalize() que irá transformar a 1º letra do que digitar em maiúsculo já que todos os índices da tupla iniciam com maiúsculo .

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).